# Python Flask SQLAlchemy Много внешних ключей

Tags: sql, python, flask, sqlalchemy

Есть две таблицы - *Студенты* и *Специальности*

Суть в том, что у *студента* есть поля - *Приоритет1*, *Приоритет*, *Приоритет3* и они должны быть связаны со *специальностями* по `id` например. А у меня SQLAlchemy ругается на множественное несоответствие ключей. Всю голову сломал с этими `parent/child relationships`.

Подскажите пожалуйста решение проблемы.

Привожу код:

```
class Student(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, nullable = False)

    UID = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, nullable = False)

    Last_Name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable = False)
    First_Name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable = False) 
    Middle_Name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable = False)

    Avg_mark = db.Column(db.Float, default = '0', nullable = False)
    Math_mark = db.Column(db.Float, default = '0', nullable = False)
    Courses_mark = db.Column(db.Float, default = '0', nullable = False)

    Privils = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable = False)

    Priority_1 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('specialty.id'), nullable = False)
    Priority_2 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('specialty.id'), nullable = False)
    Priority_3 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('specialty.id'), nullable = False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Student %r>' % (self.Last_Name)


class Specialty(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('specialty.id'), primary_key = True, nullable = False)

    Title = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable = False)
    Abbr = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable = False)
    Budg_Places = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)

    prior1 = db.relationship('Student', backref = 'prior1', foreign_keys="specialty.id")
    prior2 = db.relationship('Student', backref = 'prior2', foreign_keys="specialty.id")
    prior3 = db.relationship('Student', backref = 'prior3', foreign_keys="specialty.id")


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Speciality %r>' % (self.Title)
```

SQLAlchemy: 2.6.1

До этого пока ковырял были другие ошибки.

Текущие ошибки:

```
models.Student.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 498, in __get__
    mapper = orm.class_mapper(type)
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 421, in class_mapper
    mapper = _inspect_mapped_class(class_, configure=configure)
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 400, in _inspect_mapped_class
    mapper._configure_all()
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1167, in _configure_all
    configure_mappers()
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2768, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1710, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 183, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1628, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1653, in _process_dependent_arguments
    setattr(self, attr, attr_value())
  File "/Users/prvz/Desktop/WORK/reception-dtpa/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 281, in __call__
    x = eval(self.arg, globals(), self._dict)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста информацию о версии SqlAlchemy и точное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: А почему бы не сделать таблицу связей студенты-специальности, в которой будет три столбца: id студента, id специальности и приоритет? Не забудьте только ограничения уникальности на нее навесить, чтобы не получилось нескольких записей для одного студента с одинаковым приоритетом

Comment: @Donil Хорошая идея, наверное так и поступлю, ибо это будет самым правильным решением. Спасибо!

Comment: @Donil Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы не сделать таблицу связей студенты-специальности, в которой будет три столбца: id студента, id специальности и приоритет? Не забудьте только ограничения уникальности на нее навесить, чтобы не получилось нескольких записей для одного студента с одинаковым приоритетом